# Do Speech to text in real-time

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, wit.ai, houndify

I am developing a Voice based personal assistant using Python. I took help from some open-source projects. I have apis for speech to text engines. My assistant first records the voice, then it uses the api to send the voice and return the transcribed command. Whereas the other platforms like siri, cortana, google now, houndify and web services, they do it in real time like instantly.

How to achieve the instant speech to text like these engines?

Answer (score 1):

The Houndify Python SDK allows you to make streaming voice and text queries to the Houndify API from your Python project. You can use the StreamingHoundClient class that the SDK provides to make voice queries and enable the appropriate domains on the Houndify platform to get instant answers. While the platform is capable of converting your speech to meaning directly, if you still want to get the transcription of recorded audio, you can use the Speech to Text domain.

Here is a [link to the documentation](https://docs.houndify.com/sdks/docs/python) on how to set it up and here is a [link to the Python SDK](https://www.houndify.com/sdks#python). You would have to sign-in to access the documentation and download the SDK for Python 2.7 or Python 3.0.

This should allow you to make queries and get answers instantly.